# Trouble fitting small values with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, precision, data-fitting

I'll try to explain what I'm doing and show the error I'm getting at the end. So, I have a file with the following data:

```
1.00000000E-05  8.39843750E-02  1.28074971E-02
1.00000000E-06  6.83593750E-02  1.15548433E-02
1.00000000E-07  4.29687500E-02  9.16096828E-03
1.00000000E-08  2.73437500E-02  7.30792458E-03
1.00000000E-09  3.90625000E-02  8.73464054E-03
1.00000000E-10  2.34375000E-02  6.76582347E-03
1.00000000E-11  1.36718750E-02  5.16748303E-03
1.00000000E-12  1.56250000E-02  5.52427173E-03
```

and I need to do a fitting. I do it with

```
datfile = "data.dat"
a = 0.1; b = 0.2
f(x) = a*x**b
fit f(x) datfile u 1:2:3 yerrors via a, b
```

and obtain the values `a = 0.312672` and `b=0.116722`. Then I want to plot the points and the fitting function. But the fitting function gets "fractured" at `x = 10^-9` as you can see here->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNRJ8.png). I believe there may be something to do with the numerical precision, but couldn't figure out. My version of gnuplot is `5.2` and my code for plotting is

```
set logscale x
set logscale y
plot datfile u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars, f(x) w lines lw 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be numerically safer to use log: replace your nonlinear fit f(x)= a.x^b, by a linear one log(f(x)) = b.log(x)+log(a) ( you have a fit of the form Y=B.X+A, find A,B using your data X=log(x) and Y=log(f(x)) and then get back a,b using a=e^A, b=B)

Comment: @PicaudVincent That worked as a workaround. Thanks!